# What happens when I use while(1) in child process after fork?

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a c program which uses fork() to create child process now in child process i am running while(1) loop and in parent process I am just printing "hello World" and then exit the program. Now how to check my parent program is killed/exited but child is still running in background?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  int pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    printf("This is child\n");
    while (1)
      ;
  } else {
    printf("Hello World this is parent\n");
    return 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is all the details after execution with `ps` command output.

I have tried find processes using `ps` command of linux output is as show in picture.[Ps Command Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4RMI.png)

Comment: @Dhiman – 
The shown terminal output answers all of your question, doesn't it?

Comment: There is a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149319/new-parent-process-when-the-parent-process-dies) that discusses how a child's parent gets reassigned if the parent dies before the child. "On Linux, FreeBSD/PC-BSD, and DragonFly BSD, the parent process of orphaned children is set to the nearest ancestor process of the child that is marked as a subreaper, or process #1 if there is no ancestor subreaper process."

Comment: Print the `pid` of both process in `printf` and cross verify that with `ps` output

Comment: @Armali Yes, I saw terminal output but I am confused that in the `ps` command we can see a process named fork. so is this a child process or that is a parent process??

Comment: From your program's code it's evident that the parent terminates (`return 0;`) and doesn't continue to run. Also the new parent of the running process being `systemd` and not the shell proves that the running process is the child.

Comment: @Armali Yes, I am also thinking same. But then when I integrate my code with php code. Where I called the `fork` binary generated by `gcc` with help of `shell_exec` and `exec` function of php. in my website I am not getting immediate response once the parent process completes that php script waits for child process to finish and then shows me output on my webserver. Do you have any idea about this why such problem is occuring if parent is already exited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not getting immediate response once the parent process completes that php script waits for child process to finish and then shows me output on my webserver. Do you have any idea about this why such problem is occuring if parent is already exited?

The PHP script appears to wait for output from the `exec`ed process until end of output is indicated. Now when *the parent process completes*, the standard output is still open from the child, hence no end of output yet. If you want the script to stop waiting for further output, you can end it with `fclose(stdout)` from the child.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is to print the `pid` of both process in `printf` and cross verify that with `ps` output

Sample program

```
int main(void) {
  int pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    printf("This is child.My pid is %ld and my parent pid is %ld\n", getpid(), getppid());
    while (1)
      ;
  } else {
    printf("Hello World this is parent. My pid is %ld\n", getpid());
    return 0;
  }
```

Sample Output

```
$ ./fork
Hello World this is parent. My pid is 5784
This is child.My pid is 5785 and my parent pid is 5784
$
$
$ ps -ef | grep 5784 | grep -v grep
$
$ ps -ef | grep 5785 | grep -v grep
k+  5785     1 99 15:36 pts/8    00:00:22 ./fork
$
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the same and got the same type of output. I am confused that in the `ps` command we can see a process named fork. so is this a child process or that is a parent process?? As you can see your `ps` command also shows process name fork. can you explain this?

Comment: @Dhiman Check the `pid` printed in `ps` output. In my ouput it is printed as `5785` which matches with `This is child.My pid is 5785` So it is `child` process